# Returning a value from dataframe using columns as a range

Tags: python, pandas

Factor Dataframe:

| Code | Min | Max | Factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 100 | 1 |
| A | 101 | 300 | 2 |
| A | 301 | 800 | 3 |
| A | 800 | NaN | 4 |
| B | 0 | 100 | 2 |
| B | 101 | 300 | 4 |
| B | 301 | 800 | 6 |
| B | 800 | NaN | 8 |

The table above is used to return a factor based on two values, the 'Code' and a specific number. A specific value is provided, such as 5, 302, 253, 8000 and if that value falls between the min and max, the factor is returned.

For example:

- A, 355 = 3
- B, 9000 = 8

I have a separate table with several thousand lines with values which need to have the factor assigned.

Dataframe:

| Item | Code | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1 |
| 002 | A | 322 |
| 003 | B | 21 |
| 004 | A | 342 |
| 005 | A | 32 |
| 006 | B | 7666 |
| 007 | B | 10000 |
| 008 | B | 86 |

How do you use the pandas tool set to return the desired factor and append the relevant factor as a new column?

Comment: Kindly Add the other dataframe as well as the expected output dataframe

Comment: Done, not sure if its broken the table formatting though its shown it correct in the preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with replace missing value to `np.inf` and then filter in [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and possible missing values in `Min`, if no match in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df1)
  Code   Val
0    A   355
1    B  9000
2    C     5

print (df2)
  Code  Min    Max  Factor
0    A    0  100.0       1
1    A  101  300.0       2
2    A  301  800.0       3
3    A  800    NaN       4
4    B    0  100.0       2
5    B  101  300.0       4
6    B  301  800.0       6
7    B  800    NaN       8

df = df1.merge(df2.fillna({'Max':np.inf}), how='left', on='Code')

df3 = (df[df['Val'].between(df['Min'], df['Max']) | df['Min'].isna()]
             .drop(['Min','Max'], axis=1))
print (df3)
  Code   Val  Factor
2    A   355     3.0
7    B  9000     8.0
8    C     5     NaN
```

Comment: df = df1.merge(df2.fillna({'Max':np.inf}), how='left', on='Code')

I am getting a key error here, I have renamed my tables to ensure they share the same name.

Comment: @Hamsandwich - What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` and  `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Ok renamed the wrong table column header, finishing your solution now

Comment: Excellent, worked perfectly, just need to read my own code properly! Thank you.